# Sharekit Authorization For Twitter

Tags: iphone, twitter, sharekit

I want to authorize a user for my iphone app using Twitter.  I would like to use sharekit to do this for simplicity but I am missing something fundamental.  My understanding is that the way you do this is as follows:

```
        service=[[SHKTwitter alloc] init];
        [service authorize];
```

What is not clear to me is how I get notified once the authorization process is complete.  When I execute this code, a modal view controller pops up and the user grants access via twitter.  Authorization is successfully made and the modal view controller is dismissed.  What I don't see is any way for me to be notified once all this is complete?  What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

You could check two methods in SHKOAuthSharer (if you use OAuth to authorize):
1. - tokenAuthorizeView: didFinishWithSuccess:
2. - tokenAuthorizeCancelledView:

They where called when authorizing view is closing. So you could put your own delegate callbacks here.

Or check this https://github.com/ideashower/ShareKit/issues/187